# laravel php join query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so i just switch my website to using laravel frameworks and i just don't know how to make table join in here...

so my join in php is

```
$sql_tampil = "SELECT ar.id,ar.judul,ar.content,ar.status,ar.gambar,ar.pilihan,ar.kategori,ar.penulis,ar.tanggal,";
$sql_tampil .="k.id as kid,k.name as kname,ad.id as adid,ad.name as adname"; 
$sql_tampil .=" FROM " . artikel::$nama_tabel. " ar ";
$sql_tampil .=" LEFT JOIN " .kategori_artikel::$nama_tabel. " k ";
$sql_tampil .=" ON ar.kategori = k.id";
$sql_tampil .=" LEFT JOIN " .admin::$nama_tabel. " ad ";
$sql_tampil .=" ON ar.penulis = ad.id";
```

how to translate that kind of php join into laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the query builder documentation. This is covered in great detail.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

Comment: thank you... but i wondering how about using something like hasmany(xxxx), belongsto(xxxx), i tried that first but it just not working for simple join that only join 2 table "SELECT ad.id,ad.username,ad.cu,ad.status,ad.online,ad.offline,cu.id as cuid,cu.name as cuname FROM " .admin::$nama_tabel. " ad LEFT JOIN " .cuprimer::$nama_tabel. " cu ON ad.cu = cu.id"